# LINQ To Entities SaveChanges() not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I have a scenario where I have a form where I would like administrators to modify their exam / survey details, I am trying to update my database table with the following code.

However the code does not save my changes for the "if" part in my controller, and does not throw any error, and will just redirect me to the next page which is "EditExam2".

I am trying to update the "InformationSheetText" and "InformationConsentForm" fields.

I know the query works as the the "else" part of my code in my controller works when adding a new row into the database.

My View

```
@model  
 AppXamApplication.Models
InformationSheetViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "InformationSheet";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>InformationSheet</h2>
<h3>Survey ID: @ViewBag.CurrentExamID</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("InformationSheet", "ExamAdmin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create Information and Consent Sheet.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ImageURL, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="ImageFile" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.InformationSheetText, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.InformationSheetText, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 4, @style = "resize: none;" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Check_InformationSheet, new { @disabled = "disabled", @checked = true })
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Check_InformationSheet, new { })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.InformationConsentForm, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.InformationConsentForm, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 4, @style = "resize: none;" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Check_InformationConsentForm1, new { @disabled = "disabled", @checked = true })
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Check_InformationConsentForm1, new { })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Check_InformationConsentForm2, new { @disabled = "disabled", @checked = true })
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Check_InformationConsentForm2, new { })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Create Exam" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
 @section Scripts {
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

My model

```
public class InformationSheetViewModel
{
    public string ExamID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Choose Image To Display")]
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Enter your Information Sheet")]
    public string InformationSheetText { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Enter your Consent Form")]
    public string InformationConsentForm { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "I had read and understood the information sheet")]
    public bool Check_InformationSheet { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "I consent and agree to the information consent form")]
    public bool Check_InformationConsentForm1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "I have read, agree and consent to the information and conditions")]
    public bool Check_InformationConsentForm2 { get; set; }

}
```

My Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult InformationSheet(string id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentExamID = id;
        using (var ctx = new AppXamApplicationEntities())
        {
            var query = ctx.InformationConsentAndSheets.Where(x => x.ExamID.Equals(id)).Select(x => new InformationSheetViewModel()
            {
               ExamID = id,
               InformationSheetText = x.InformationSheetText,
               InformationConsentForm = x.InformationSheetText
           }).FirstOrDefault();
           return View(query);                    
        }
    }
     return View();
}


[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "ExamAdmin")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult InformationSheet(string id, InformationSheetViewModel model)
{
    using (var ctx = new AppXamApplicationEntities())
    {
       InformationConsentAndSheet query = ctx.InformationConsentAndSheets.Where(x => x.ExamID.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();
       if (query != null)
       {   
           //To insert picture into database as well as folder
           string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(model.ImageFile.FileName);
           string extension = Path.GetExtension(model.ImageFile.FileName);
           fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
           model.ImageURL = "~/Image/" + fileName;
           fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), fileName);
           model.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);

           query = new InformationConsentAndSheet()
           { 
              ExamID = id,
              ImageURL = model.ImageURL,
              InformationSheetText = model.InformationSheetText,
              InformationConsentForm = model.InformationConsentForm
           };
           ctx.SaveChanges();
       }
       else
       {
            //To insert picture into database as well as folder
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(model.ImageFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(model.ImageFile.FileName);
            fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
            model.ImageURL = "~/Image/" + fileName;
            fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), fileName);
            model.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);

            query = new InformationConsentAndSheet()
            {
               ExamID = id,
               ImageURL = model.ImageURL,
               InformationConsentForm = model.InformationConsentForm,
               InformationSheetText = model.InformationSheetText
            };
            ctx.InformationConsentAndSheets.Add(query);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    return RedirectToAction("EditExam2");
}
```

}

I am very perplexed to what is wrong with my code, any form of help will be very appreciated as I am extremely new to MVC in general.

Comment: In the `query != null` branch you never add the new entity to the collection before saving, so there is nothing to save.

Comment: Your form does not post back any value for `id` so its `null` and the `else` block will always be executed

Comment: And the code in you if block makes no sense. You get the object that you want to update from the db, but the ignore it,and create a new object, but never add that object to the context, so there is nothing to save

Comment: Its also not clear what `ImageURL = model.ImageURL,` is for since there is no for control for `ImageURL` and that will always be `null`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated the code to show what is my ImageURL meant for, but how do i add the object to the context in order to save the changes

Comment: @Richard, so how do I add the new entity to the collection before saving?

Comment: You don't in the case of editing an existing object. You get the object from the db as you are doing, and then you update its properties and call `.SaveChanges()` - you do not create a new object

Comment: And for creating new objects, you don't first call the database to get it when you know it does not exist (that is just a waste of resources)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to send your Id of survey when you want to edit. It can be done easly by route parameters in your form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("InformationSheet", "ExamAdmin", new { id = ViewBag.CurrentExamID }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Your code for edit existing item is a little bit wrong. You need to, well, modify existing InformationConsentAndSheet and not creating new.

```
       InformationConsentAndSheet query = ctx.InformationConsentAndSheets.Where(x => x.ExamID.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();
       if (query != null)
       {   
          // work with files

           query.ExamID = id;
           query.ImageURL = model.ImageURL;
           query.InformationSheetText = model.InformationSheetText;
           query.InformationConsentForm = model.InformationConsentForm;

           ctx.Entry(query).State = EntityState.Modified;
           ctx.SaveChanges();
       }
```

Before submiting changes you need to specify that query have been edited and needs to be saved.

Hope its helps.